# how do I mount a second hard drive?

Tags: mount, hard-drive, automount

My laptop has a 32GB SSD on which I've installed Ubuntu, and a 500GB HDD where I plan to store my files. When I try to download big files (like blu ray movies) it says it can't because my HDD is not big enough. How do I tell the OS that it can use the free 500GB on the other drive?

Answer (score 0):

you need to switch download folder to the external hard driver. The default place for all downloads is the folder called **Downloads** but this can be changed in the program.

so go to settings in the program you are using and select your hard drive instead of your downloads folder. It's really easy, comment the program if you have any problems and I'll guide you better.

Comment: Hello! The other harddrive doesnt appear. I m using  Transmission bittorent client and i tried changing the default folder it downloads to, but i couldnt find the hitachi hdd with the 500 gb. Any ideas?

Comment: @user256549 is the hard drive mounted? Can you navigate to it via folders and see what it contains?

Comment: no i cant, how do i mount?

Comment: @user256549 Click on a folder and go to computer. Then click on the icon that matches to the hard drive. Then it will be mounted automatically. How is the hard drive connected?